# What is the next number? (an accounting interview question)

Tags: number-sequence

I got this question from an accounting interview:

What is the next number?

> `0 1 3 8 56 65 ?`

What are the rules of the sequence?

Comment: It's not 65 instead of 63, is it?

Comment: Correct: 65, I updated my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is:

> **715**

Reason:

> The differences are the odd numbers alternating like this: +1, x3, +5, x7,+9, x11

Comment: But don't take the job if they offer. That accounting company isn't the one you want